# What is the validity of the apple VPP account?

Tags: ios, xcode

We have created the VPP account in the last year. So, anyone please let us know how to check the validity of the same?

Answer (score 0):

The VPP account itself does not expire, the VPP token used by your MDM expires yearly. You can check the expiration from the MDM itself and upload a new .vpptoken file as well. To renew the token go to Account Summary > Manage Distribution > Download Token.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have downloaded the .vpptoken. Can you let me know where to check the MDM expiration (link) and where to upload the .vpptoken.

Comment: Which MDM server (i.e. MobileIron, Intune, MaaS360, etc.) are you using ?